# Where are screen saver applications on Slackware 14?

Tags: linux, unix, slackware

I want to find out where screensaver applications are in Slackware 14, because screensaver "sonar" manpage says it has to be setuid.

Answer (score 2):

They should be in `/usr/lib/xscreensaver`. In my Arch Linux system:

```
renan:/usr/lib/xscreensaver % ls -la sonar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 99824 Out 18 01:00 sonar*
```